# JMESPath to generate an array of objects from an object of objects

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2, jq, jmespath

I have the following example json document (object of objects):

```
{
   "key1": { "key1a": [{"key1aa": "value1aa"}, {"key1ab": "value1ab"}],... },
   "key2": { "key2a": [{"key2aa": "value2aa"}, {"key2ab": "value2ab"}],... },
   ...
}
```

And I try to reshape it to an Array of that objects like

```
[
  { "key1": { "key1a": [{"key1aa": "value1aa"}, {"key1ab": "value1ab"}],... }},
  { "key2": { "key2a": [{"key2aa": "value2aa"}, {"key2ab": "value2ab"}],... }},
  ...
]
```

What I can use is JMESPath inside Ansible's jinja2 filter json_query

How is that possible?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 2):

Given *my_dict* the play

```
  vars:
    my_dict:
      key1: { "key1a": ["key1aa": "value1aa", "key1ab": "value1ab"]}
      key2: { "key2a": ["key2aa": "value2aa", "key2ab": "value2ab"]}
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ my_list|default([]) + [{item.key: item.value}] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_dict|dict2items }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_list|to_json }}"
```

gives

```
msg: '[{"key2": {"key2a": [{"key2aa": "value2aa"}, {"key2ab": "value2ab"}]}},
       {"key1": {"key1a": [{"key1aa": "value1aa"}, {"key1ab": "value1ab"}]}}]'
```

The output was printed with `yaml` callback (`export ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml`). Then the output was split manually after the first item of the list.

---

**json_query**

It is also possible to create the list with `jmespath` i.e. `json_query`. For example, the task below gives the same result

```
- set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ my_dict|
                 dict2items|
                 json_query('[].[{key: key, value: value}]')|
                 map('items2dict')|
                 list }}"
```

---

**to_nice_yaml**

It's easier to see the data's structure when printed with the filter `to_nice_yaml`. For example

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_list|to_nice_yaml }}"
```

gives

```
  msg: |-
    -   key2:
            key2a:
            -   key2aa: value2aa
            -   key2ab: value2ab
    -   key1:
            key1a:
            -   key1aa: value1aa
            -   key1ab: value1ab
```

---

**filter_plugins**

It's also possible to use custom [Filter plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins). For example with the plugin

```
$ cat filter_plugins/dict_utils.py

def dict2list(d):
    l = []
    for i in d:
        h = {i:d[i]}
        l.append(h)
    return l

class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'dict2list': dict2list
        }
```

the task below gives the same result

```
- set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ my_dict|dict2list }}"
```

---

For your convenience:

- [source code of the playbook](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/blob/master/examples/example-103/dict2items-4.yml)
- [filter plugins](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with jmespath (i.e. json_query) **alone** unless you are ready to loose the top level key. In this case, you can simply apply the wildcard jmespath expression (i.e. `*`) to your object.

If you do not want to loose the top level keys and you still want to keep jmespath as part of the equation, the following example meets those requirements but needs some more filters.

Some details about the scenario:

- Transform the initial hash to a list of `{key: XXX, value: YYY}` hashes with [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter)
- Use `json_query` to transform that list of hashes (i.e. `[{}, {}]`) to a list of list of hashes (i.e. `[[{}], [{}]]`)
- Map the [`items2dict` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#items2dict-filter) on each element of the result list
- Finally the [`list` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#list) will transform the temporary object from `map` to a usable list.

```
---
- name: Transform hash to list with jmespath and dict2items/items2dict
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    my_object: {
      "key1": { "key1a": ["key1aa": "value1aa", "key1ab": "value1ab"] },
      "key2": { "key2a": ["key2aa": "value2aa", "key2ab": "value2ab"] }
    }

  tasks:
    - name: Do transform with json_query
      debug:
        msg: >-
          {{
            my_object
            | dict2items
            | json_query('[].[{key: key, value: value}]')
            | map('items2dict')
            | list
          }}
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [Transform hash to list with jmespath and dict2items/items2dict] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Do transform with json_query] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "key1": {
                "key1a": [
                    {
                        "key1aa": "value1aa"
                    },
                    {
                        "key1ab": "value1ab"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "key2": {
                "key2a": [
                    {
                        "key2aa": "value2aa"
                    },
                    {
                        "key2ab": "value2ab"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in that way, I will loose the keys 'key1','key2','keyX' which are important.

Comment: Good point, I was a little fast. Meanwhile I'm affraid it makes this not feasible with jmespath at all.

Comment: It not feasible with jmespath.... **alone**. Please see my updated answer where it is still part of the equation (but uses some more filters).

Answer (score 1):

Note that your array in both examples is not correct JSON syntax (array elements should be inside an object).

So, given this example:

```
cat file
{
  "key1": { "key1a": [{"key1aa": "value1aa"}, {"key1ab": "value1ab"}] },
  "key2": { "key2a": [{"key2aa": "value2aa"}, {"key2ab": "value2ab"}] }
}
```

You can use `jq`:

```
<file jq 'to_entries|map({(.key):.value})'
```

Comment: Note that it is not a correct json syntax for sure, but still valid yaml leading to the exact same data structure as the one you fixed in your answer. [yq](https://pypi.org/project/yq/) (based on jq) can interpret it without any problems

Comment: A yeah, your right. My issue. My JSON here is not valid json syntax. I corrected it.

Comment: I try to prevent jq in my ansible because of additional dependencies. And my json object is respond from elastic roles API via the Ansible's uri module. They did not respond an arry. Don't know why they do it in spaces API but not in the roles API